# How to set lines, arrows and text in this block diagram on tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

Im quite new learning tikz, it rocks!. Well, Im trying to get the following block diagram working, but having kinda trouble:

[image: Image that I want]

And this is what I got so far:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[arr/.style={->,thick}, line/.style={thick},
nonterminal/.style={rectangle, minimum size=12mm, very thick, draw=black!50!black!50, top color=white, bottom color=blue!50!black!20}, >= triangle 90, font = \small
]

\matrix[row sep=20mm,column sep=5mm] {
% First row:
\node (ic)  [nonterminal] {$\begin{array}{cc}Impedance\\control \end{array}$}; &
\node (id)  [nonterminal] {$\begin{array}{cc}Inverse\\dynamics \end{array}$}; &
\node (rme) [nonterminal] {$\begin{array}{cc}Robot \: manipulator\\and \: environment \end{array}$}; & \\
% Second row:
& \node (dk) [nonterminal] {$\begin{array}{cc}Direct\\kinematics \end{array}$}; & \\
};

\draw [->] (ic) -- (id)  node[pos=0.5, above] {$\alpha$};
\draw [->] (id) -- (rme) node[pos=0.5, above] {$\tau$};
\draw [->] (rme.15)   -- ++ (1.8,0)   node[pos=0.3, above, yshift = -2] {$h_{e}$} -| ++ (0,-5) -| (ic.230);
\draw [->] (rme.0)    -- ++ (1.2,0)   node[pos=0.4, above, yshift = -2] {$q$} -| ++ (0,-3.50) --   (dk.-10);
\draw [->] (rme.-15)  -- ++ (0.6,0)   node[pos=0.8, above, yshift = -2] {$\dot{q}$} -| ++ (0,-2.50) -- (dk.10);
\draw [->] (dk.170)   -- ++ (-1,-0) node[pos=0.5, above, yshift = -3] {$p_{e} \, R{e}$}  -| (ic.310);
\draw [->] (dk.190)   -- ++ (-1.4,-0) node[pos=0.7, above, yshift = -3] {$v_{e}$} -|  (ic.270);


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{center}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Well there are a couple of things, I don´t know how to do:

1) How to make double lines on the text inside the boxes for better fitting?

**Solved, with arrays for multilines. Is there another way to do this?**

2) How do I properly draw the lines and arrows?

Still need to draw left and right arrows for the first and last block...

3) How to place text?

Kinda solved.

I appreciate all of your answers.

Comment: See my question and neat answers [MIMO Block Diagrams](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19142/block-diagrams-multi-input-multi-output-components-in-tikz) and nice to see some robotics around :)

Comment: @percusse  I used yours array notation to create multilines boxes, I edited my code and questions. Thanks :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The way I always do this kind of thing is, draw it on paper. Draw some simple help lines for size and then start defining coordinates you can use to build up the image. Make coordinates for node placement, where edges meet and start thinking about how to connect to the nodes (anchors). The last step is then to do the finetuning on label placement and small modifications. This led me to the following code, hopefully it will clarify the approach and help you tackle this kind of diagram:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
  %coordinates
  \coordinate (orig)   at (0,0);
  \coordinate (LLD)    at (4,0);
  \coordinate (AroneA) at (-1/2,11/2);
  \coordinate (ArtwoA) at (-1/2,5);
  \coordinate (ArthrA) at (-1/2,9/2);
  \coordinate (LLA)    at (1,4);
  \coordinate (LLB)    at (4,4);
  \coordinate (LLC)    at (7,4);
  \coordinate (AroneC) at (25/2,11/2);
  \coordinate (ArtwoC) at (25/2,5);
  \coordinate (ArthrC) at (25/2,9/2);
  \coordinate (conCBD) at (21/2,9/2);
  \coordinate (conCB)  at (21/2,7/2);
  \coordinate (coCBD)  at (11,5);
  \coordinate (coCB)   at (11,3);
  \coordinate (conCBA) at (23/2,11/2);
  \coordinate (conCA)  at (23/2,5/2);

  %nodes
  \node[draw, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=2cm, anchor=south west, text width=2cm, align=center] (A) at (LLA) {Impedance\\control};
  \node[draw, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=2cm, anchor=south west, text width=2cm, align=center] (B) at (LLB) {Inverse\\Dynamics};
  \node[draw, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=2cm, anchor=south west, text width=2cm, align=center] (C) at (LLC) {Manipulator\\and\\environment};
  \node[draw, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=2cm, anchor=south west, text width=2cm, align=center] (D) at (LLD) {Direct\\kinematics};

  %edges
  \draw[->] (AroneA) -- node[above]{$p_d, R_d$} ($(A.180) + (0,1/2)$);
  \draw[->] (ArtwoA) -- node[above]{$v_d$} (A.180);
  \draw[->] (ArthrA) -- node[above]{$v_d$} ($(A.180) + (0,-1/2)$);

  \draw[->] (A.0) -- node[above] {$\alpha$} (B.180);
  \draw[->] (B.0) -- node[above] {$\tau$} (C.180);

  \draw[->] ($(C.0) + (0,1/2)$) -- node[above, pos=0.2]{$h_e$} (AroneC);
  \draw[->] (C.0) -- node[above, pos=0.2]{$q$} (ArtwoC);
  \draw[->] ($(C.0) + (0,-1/2)$) -- node[above, pos=0.2]{$q$} (ArthrC);

  \path[fill] (conCBD) circle[radius=1pt] (conCB) circle[radius=1pt];
  \path[draw,->] (conCBD) -- (conCB) -| ($(B.270) + (1/2,0)$);

  \path[fill] (coCBD) circle[radius=1pt] (coCB) circle[radius=1pt];
  \path[draw,->] (coCBD)  -- (coCB) -| (B.270);

  \path[fill] (conCBA) circle[radius=1pt] (conCA) circle[radius=1pt];
  \path[draw,->] (conCBA) -- (conCA) -| ($(B.270) + (-1/2,0)$);

  \path[draw,->] (conCB) |- ($(D.0) + (0,1/2)$);
  \path[draw,->] (coCB)  |- ($(D.0) + (0,-1/2)$);

  \path[draw,->] (conCA) |- ($(A.270) + (-1/2,0) + (0,-9/2)$) -- ($(A.270) + (-1/2,0)$);

  \path[draw,->] ($(D.180) + (0,1/2)$)  -| node[above,pos=0.2] {$p_e,r_e$} ($(A.270) + (1/2,0)$);
  \path[draw,->] ($(D.180) + (0,-1/2)$) -| node[above,pos=0.15] {$v_e$} (A.270);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{center}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: TikZ diagram]

Comment: This is great thanks. I will study your code /  technique and apply it to others diagrams I have to do

Answer (score 4):

3) To get the text labels for the connections, you can use `node` with the optional `pos` keyword, e.g.:

```
\draw [->] (ic) -- (id) node[pos=0.5, above] {$\alpha$};
```

See Sections 15.8 and 15.9 of the tikz/pgf manual for more details.

Comment: A useful little piece of information for this diagram is that when a line is bent (via `|-` or `-|`) then the position `0.5` refers to the bend, *not* to the halfway point of the line (in practice this is more useful).  This will help with positioning the `p_e, R_e` and `v_e` labels.

Comment: Thanks, this really helped me to get the labels working. I had to use yshift to get them close to the lines.