# Variable/counter for each object/instance using a template with \tikzset and /.style?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

So I have made a 'template'-shape using `\tikzset` and `/.style` or `\tikzstyle` and if I understand it correctly, one can add objects with the same style as the template. Is it possible to modify the `\tikzset` or `\.style` or `tikzstyle` such that each object or instance has its own variable/counter?

For instance, I try to make a block diagram as in [Block Diagrams using Tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175969/block-diagrams-using-tikz). It's easy if each block has 1 input and 1 output. It becomes a little complicated if the blocks have more inputs and outputs. In the latter case with multiple i/o, I have to divide the starting points of outputs and ending points of input equally along the side of a block.

An example of multiple i/o

[image]
https://www.mathworks.com/help/examples/control/win64/xxinterconnections16.png

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean, can you make a complete example demonstrating what you mean?

Comment: We certainly would need to see the 'template' and how you're using it to stand a chance of answering this. If you don't know if you can modify it, who have the advantage of seeing the code, how should we know, who do not?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: I edited the question and hope it's a little bit more clear :)

Comment: Like this ? [block-diagrams-multi-input-multi-output-components-in-tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19142/block-diagrams-multi-input-multi-output-components-in-tikz)