# How to draw automatically parallel lines?

Tags: tikz-pgf, signal-processing

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
         signal/.style = coordinate,
         block/.style = {
                         draw,
                         rectangle,
                         minimum height = 2em,
                         minimum width = 4em
                        }
        }
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}

    \node[signal] (input) {};
    \node[
          block,
          right = of input
         ] (block 1) {};
    \node[
          block,
          right = of block 1
         ] (block 2) {};
    \node[
          signal,
          right = of block 2
         ] (output) {};
    \draw
      [->] (input) -- (block 1);
    \draw
      [->] (block 1) -- (block 2);
    \draw
      [->] (block 2) -- (output);

  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Gives:

[image: result]

I wish (the lines and arrows shouldn't be bold):

[image: wish]

Is it possible to do this more or less automatically, without to draw each of the three lines by hand. Even the place of the three lines should be set automatically. That means: The middle line should placed on the vertical middle. The above and below lines should be symmetrically above and below the middle line.

Thank you for your help and effort in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make use of the `\foreach` loop

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
         signal/.style = coordinate,
         block/.style = {
                         draw,
                         rectangle,
                         minimum height = 2em,
                         minimum width = 4em
                        }
         }
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}

  \node[signal] (input) {};
  \node[
        block,
        right = of input
       ] (block 1) {};
  \node[
        block,
        right = of block 1
       ] (block 2) {};
  \node[
        signal,
        right = of block 2
       ] (output) {};
  \draw
    [->] (input) -- (block 1);
  \foreach \k in {-1,0,1}{
    \draw [->] ([yshift=\k*.2cm]block 1.east) -- ([yshift=\k*.2cm]block 2.west);
    \draw [->] ([yshift=\k*.2cm]block 2.east) -- ([yshift=\k*.2cm]output.west);
  }
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: result]

I am shifting the positions of the arrows up and down by a certain amount depending on the value of `\k` (`-1`, `0`, and finally `1`).

Answer (score 6):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
         signal/.style = coordinate,
         block/.style = {
                         draw,
                         rectangle,
                         minimum height = 2em,
                         minimum width = 4em
                        }
        }
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,positioning}
\tikzset{triple line with arrows/.style args={#1,#2,#3}{decorate,decoration={markings,%
mark=at position 0 with {\coordinate (ta-base-1) at (0,4pt);
\coordinate (ta-base-2) at (0,0pt);
\coordinate (ta-base-3) at (0,-4pt);},
mark=at position 1 with {\draw[#1] (ta-base-1) -- (0,4pt);
\draw[#2] (ta-base-2) -- (0,0pt);
\draw[#3] (ta-base-3) -- (0,-4pt);}}}}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}

    \node[signal] (input) {};
    \node[
          block,
          right = of input
         ] (block 1) {};
    \node[
          block,
          right = of block 1
         ] (block 2) {};
    \node[
          signal,
          right = of block 2
         ] (output) {};
    \draw
      [->] (input) -- (block 1);
    \draw
      [triple line with arrows={->,->,->}] (block 1) -- (block 2);
    \draw
      [triple line with arrows={->,->,->}] (block 2) -- (output);

  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM**: Just for fun: a slightly more flexible version.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
         signal/.style = coordinate,
         block/.style = {
                         draw,
                         rectangle,
                         minimum height = 2em,
                         minimum width = 4em
                        }
        }
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,positioning}
\pgfkeys{tikz/.cd,
         triple line distance/.store in =\triplelinedist,
         triple line distance=4pt
}
\tikzset{triple line with arrows/.style args={#1,#2,#3}{decorate,decoration={markings,%
mark=at position 0 with {\coordinate (ta-base-1) at (0,\triplelinedist);
\coordinate (ta-base-2) at (0,0pt);
\coordinate (ta-base-3) at (0,-\triplelinedist);},
mark=at position 1 with {\draw[#1] (ta-base-1) -- (0,\triplelinedist);
\draw[#2] (ta-base-2) -- (0,0pt);
\draw[#3] (ta-base-3) -- (0,-\triplelinedist);}}}}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}

    \node[signal] (input) {};
    \node[
          block,
          right = of input
         ] (block 1) {};
    \node[
          block,
          right = of block 1
         ] (block 2) {};
    \node[
          signal,
          right = of block 2
         ] (output) {};
    \draw
      [->] (input) -- (block 1);
    \draw
      [triple line with arrows={->,->,->}] (block 1) -- (block 2);
    \draw
      [triple line with arrows={->,->,->},triple line distance=5pt] (block 2) -- (output);

  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Shamelessly quoting my own answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/439852/74459) (slightly adjusted for this case).

I defined a new shape `block` which has three options that can be given to the style as `block={inputs=<inputs>,outputs=<outputs>,io spacing=<length>}`:

- `inputs` Arbitrary integer number of inputs, defaults to 1
- `outputs` Arbitrary integer number of outputs, defaults to 1
- `io spacing` Spacing between in- and outputs, defaults to 5mm

With this shape/style we can draw:

[image]

With only (also uses the `positioning` library, see the MWE at the bottom):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[block={outputs=3}](node1){};
    \node[block={inputs=3,outputs=3},right=of node1](node2){};

    \draw[<-] (node1.input 1) -- ++(-1,0);

    \foreach \i in {1,...,3}{
        \draw[->] (node1.output \i) -- (node2.input \i);
        \draw[->] (node2.output \i) --++(1,0);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This might be a little overkill for your problem, but who knows, you might have some additional demands that can be met with this :)

The complete shape definition is:

```
\makeatletter
\newdimen\block@iospacing
\newdimen\block@height

\newif\if@block@flip

\tikzset{
    block/.code={
        \pgfkeys{
            /block/.cd,
            #1
        }
        \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\block@height}{%
            max(10mm, int(max(\block@inputs,\block@outputs) * \block@iospacing))}
        \tikzset{
            draw,
            align=center,
            minimum width = 15mm,
            minimum height = \block@height,
            shape=block
        }
    }
}
\pgfkeys{
    /block/.is family,
    /block/.cd,
    inputs/.code={
        \pgfmathparse{int(#1)}
        \let\block@inputs=\pgfmathresult
    },
    inputs=1,
    outputs/.code={
        \pgfmathparse{int(#1)}
        \let\block@outputs=\pgfmathresult
    },
    outputs=1,
    io spacing/.code=\setlength\block@iospacing{#1},
    io spacing=5mm,
    flip/.is choice,
    flip/true/.code={\@block@fliptrue\def\@block@flipbool{1}},
    flip/false/.code={\@block@flipfalse\def\@block@flipbool{0}},
    flip/.default=true,
    flip=false,
}

\pgfdeclareshape{block}{
    \inheritsavedanchors[from={rectangle}]
    \savedanchor\centerpoint{%
        \pgf@x=.5\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox%
        \pgf@y=.5\ht\pgfnodeparttextbox%
        \advance\pgf@y by-.5\dp\pgfnodeparttextbox%
    }
    \inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle]
    \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north west}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north east}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{center}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{text}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{west}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{east}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid west}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid east}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base west}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base east}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south west}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south east}
    \savedmacro\blockinputs{%
        \pgfmathparse{int(\block@inputs)}%
        \let\blockinputs=\pgfmathresult}%
    \savedmacro\blockoutputs{%
        \pgfmathparse{int(\block@outputs)}%
        \let\blockoutputs=\pgfmathresult}%
    \savedmacro\blockmaxio{%
        \pgfmathparse{int(max(\block@inputs,\block@outputs))}%
        \let\blockmaxio=\pgfmathresult}%
    \savedmacro\blockflip{%
        \pgfmathparse{\@block@flipbool}%
        \let\blockflip=\pgfmathresult}%
    \saveddimen\halfwidth{\pgfmathsetlength\pgf@x{%
            \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum width}/2}\pgfmathresult}
    \saveddimen\halfheight{\pgfmathsetlength\pgf@x{%
            \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum height}/2}\pgfmathresult}
    \saveddimen\iospacing{\pgfmathsetlength\pgf@x{%
            \block@iospacing}\pgfmathresult}
    \inheritbackgroundpath[from={rectangle}]
    \pgfutil@g@addto@macro\pgf@sh@s@block{%
        \pgfmathloop%
        \ifnum\pgfmathcounter>\blockinputs\relax%
        \else%
        \pgfutil@ifundefined{pgf@anchor@block@input \pgfmathcounter}{%
            \expandafter\xdef\csname pgf@anchor@block@input %
            \pgfmathcounter\endcsname{\noexpand%
                \pgf@sh@lib@block@in@anchor{\pgfmathcounter}%
            }%
        }{}
        \repeatpgfmathloop%
        \pgfmathloop%
        \ifnum\pgfmathcounter>\blockoutputs\relax%
        \else%
        \pgfutil@ifundefined{pgf@anchor@block@output \pgfmathcounter}{%
            \expandafter\xdef\csname pgf@anchor@block@output %
            \pgfmathcounter\endcsname{\noexpand%
                \pgf@sh@lib@block@out@anchor{\pgfmathcounter}%
            }%
        }{}
        \repeatpgfmathloop%
    }%
}

\def\pgf@sh@lib@block@in@anchor#1{%
    \pgf@process{\centerpoint}%
    \pgf@ya=\pgf@y%
    \ifnum\blockflip=0\relax%
        \pgf@process{\southwest}%
    \else%
        \pgf@process{\northeast}%
    \fi%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@y{\pgf@ya + (0.5*(\blockinputs+1)-#1)*\iospacing}
}
\def\pgf@sh@lib@block@out@anchor#1{%
    \pgf@process{\centerpoint}%
    \pgf@ya=\pgf@y%
    \ifnum\blockflip=0\relax%
        \pgf@process{\northeast}%
    \else%
        \pgf@process{\southwest}%
    \fi%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@y{\pgf@ya + (0.5*(\blockoutputs+1)-#1)*\iospacing}
}
\makeatother
```

MWE (`copy-past`able):

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=2mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\makeatletter
\newdimen\block@iospacing
\newdimen\block@height

\newif\if@block@flip

\tikzset{
    block/.code={
        \pgfkeys{
            /block/.cd,
            #1
        }
        \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\block@height}{%
            max(10mm, int(max(\block@inputs,\block@outputs) * \block@iospacing))}
        \tikzset{
            draw,
            align=center,
            minimum width = 15mm,
            minimum height = \block@height,
            shape=block
        }
    }
}
\pgfkeys{
    /block/.is family,
    /block/.cd,
    inputs/.code={
        \pgfmathparse{int(#1)}
        \let\block@inputs=\pgfmathresult
    },
    inputs=1,
    outputs/.code={
        \pgfmathparse{int(#1)}
        \let\block@outputs=\pgfmathresult
    },
    outputs=1,
    io spacing/.code=\setlength\block@iospacing{#1},
    io spacing=5mm,
    flip/.is choice,
    flip/true/.code={\@block@fliptrue\def\@block@flipbool{1}},
    flip/false/.code={\@block@flipfalse\def\@block@flipbool{0}},
    flip/.default=true,
    flip=false,
}

\pgfdeclareshape{block}{
    \inheritsavedanchors[from={rectangle}]
    \savedanchor\centerpoint{%
        \pgf@x=.5\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox%
        \pgf@y=.5\ht\pgfnodeparttextbox%
        \advance\pgf@y by-.5\dp\pgfnodeparttextbox%
    }
    \inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle]
    \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north west}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north east}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{center}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{text}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{west}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{east}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid west}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid east}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base west}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base east}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south west}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south east}
    \savedmacro\blockinputs{%
        \pgfmathparse{int(\block@inputs)}%
        \let\blockinputs=\pgfmathresult}%
    \savedmacro\blockoutputs{%
        \pgfmathparse{int(\block@outputs)}%
        \let\blockoutputs=\pgfmathresult}%
    \savedmacro\blockmaxio{%
        \pgfmathparse{int(max(\block@inputs,\block@outputs))}%
        \let\blockmaxio=\pgfmathresult}%
    \savedmacro\blockflip{%
        \pgfmathparse{\@block@flipbool}%
        \let\blockflip=\pgfmathresult}%
    \saveddimen\halfwidth{\pgfmathsetlength\pgf@x{%
            \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum width}/2}\pgfmathresult}
    \saveddimen\halfheight{\pgfmathsetlength\pgf@x{%
            \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum height}/2}\pgfmathresult}
    \saveddimen\iospacing{\pgfmathsetlength\pgf@x{%
            \block@iospacing}\pgfmathresult}
    \inheritbackgroundpath[from={rectangle}]
    \pgfutil@g@addto@macro\pgf@sh@s@block{%
        \pgfmathloop%
        \ifnum\pgfmathcounter>\blockinputs\relax%
        \else%
        \pgfutil@ifundefined{pgf@anchor@block@input \pgfmathcounter}{%
            \expandafter\xdef\csname pgf@anchor@block@input %
            \pgfmathcounter\endcsname{\noexpand%
                \pgf@sh@lib@block@in@anchor{\pgfmathcounter}%
            }%
        }{}
        \repeatpgfmathloop%
        \pgfmathloop%
        \ifnum\pgfmathcounter>\blockoutputs\relax%
        \else%
        \pgfutil@ifundefined{pgf@anchor@block@output \pgfmathcounter}{%
            \expandafter\xdef\csname pgf@anchor@block@output %
            \pgfmathcounter\endcsname{\noexpand%
                \pgf@sh@lib@block@out@anchor{\pgfmathcounter}%
            }%
        }{}
        \repeatpgfmathloop%
    }%
}

\def\pgf@sh@lib@block@in@anchor#1{%
    \pgf@process{\centerpoint}%
    \pgf@ya=\pgf@y%
    \ifnum\blockflip=0\relax%
        \pgf@process{\southwest}%
    \else%
        \pgf@process{\northeast}%
    \fi%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@y{\pgf@ya + (0.5*(\blockinputs+1)-#1)*\iospacing}
}
\def\pgf@sh@lib@block@out@anchor#1{%
    \pgf@process{\centerpoint}%
    \pgf@ya=\pgf@y%
    \ifnum\blockflip=0\relax%
        \pgf@process{\northeast}%
    \else%
        \pgf@process{\southwest}%
    \fi%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@y{\pgf@ya + (0.5*(\blockoutputs+1)-#1)*\iospacing}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[block={outputs=3}](node1){};
        \node[block={inputs=3,outputs=3},right=of node1](node2){};

        \draw[<-] (node1.input 1) -- ++(-1,0);

        \foreach \i in {1,...,3}{
            \draw[->] (node1.output \i) -- (node2.input \i);
            \draw[->] (node2.output \i) --++(1,0);
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```